# how to know whether upgrading, repairing or uninstalling in installscript

Tags: installshield, installscript

I'm trying to write some **InstallScript** code in **Basic MSI** project. I would like to know how to determine whether an install is *Upgrading* or *Repairing* or *Uninstalling*.

None of these works in **InstallScript** -

```
 REMOVE~="ALL"
 NOT Installed
 REINSTALL<>""
 PATCH<>""
 REMOVEALLMODE
```

I found [this blog](http://www.installationdeveloper.com/3086/detecting-whether-an-install-is-initial-maintenance-or-uninstall/) and that **MAINTENANCE** flag works. But it can only determine whether it's Initial Install or Not. Always "TRUE" in Upgrade, Repair and Uninstall.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using an InstallScript project, or InstallScript code in some sort of MSI project (either Basic MSI or InstallScript MSI)? Most of the items you mention are MSI-related, and thus are either irrelevant or take extra steps to use in InstallScript code.

Comment: @MichaelUrman updated. it's Basic MSI project.

Comment: Short answer: call [MsiEvaluateCondition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370104.aspx) (it's available in InstallScript) with those as conditions.

Comment: It works, finally. Thanks
Can you post this again as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example strings you posted are all [examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368561.aspx) of Windows Installer [Conditions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368012.aspx). You can't just cut and paste those into an InstallScript `if`. Instead you have to call [MsiEvaluateCondition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370104.aspx) to have Windows Installer process them.

```
// Note that MSICONDITION_TRUE is 1; I forgot to test whether it's defined
if MSICONDITION_TRUE = MsiEvaluateCondition(hMSI, "Not Installed") then
    MessageBox("First-time installation", INFORMATION;
endif;
```

Note that this only applies in MSI-based installations. For a pure InstallScript project, the Windows Installer APIs are largely unavailable or unusable, and you should instead place code in the proper event handler (such as OnFirstUIBefore).